# Multithreaded loops in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have two "FOR" loops and one permutation in it (which is 3 for-each loops). The permutation creates a 3 character string and works by looping through an array of characters. This work fine for me. Here is the working part.

```
Dim chars() = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}

        For varXR = 25 To 35
            For varEVD = 0 To 99
                For Each x1 In chars
                    For Each x2 In chars
                        For Each x3 In chars

                        Console.Writeline(varXR & varEVD & x1 & x2 & x3)

                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

I need to create a thread for each varEVD (100 threads) and make each thread work with the permutation loops. And when these threads are complete, move on and continue with the exact same thing for the next varXR.. any example would be appreciated.

Oh, and i need every varEVD loop to have same range (0-99). Thanks!

EDIT: The application is a console application!

Comment: Have you tried something? An easy way to do this is to use PLINQ or Parallel.For

Comment: What for? It would significantly slow things down. Hint x1 & x2 & x3 could be done once...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes i tried to create a thread list but when it's time to move on the next varXR it simply doesn't. It seems that at least one of the threads (or more?) does not terminate (?) because i used an event handler to print completed threads and it doesn't return all of them. It simply waits doing nothing after the first varXR loop :/

Comment: What do you mean by thread list? Where's the code you used? PLINQ or Parallel.For do not deal with raw threads.

Comment: I mean: Dim EVDThread As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoLoopSub))

Comment: Which task are you trying to solve? Please describe the original task, not the method you want to approach it with. We can then review the method you have, and suggest something, maybe even a totally different approach.

Comment: this is the task actually :) these loops are the main part of the task i need to multi-thread

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to create 100 threads. The parallel processing is still limited by the number of core you have.

It's hard to see what you're trying to actually do here but you could remove some of the code out of the loop. If you really need to do a WriteLine, then that'll be the slowest part of your code no mather if you have threads or not.

```
    Dim chars() = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}
    Dim combinations As New List(Of String)

    For Each x1 In chars
        For Each x2 In chars
            For Each x3 In chars
                combinations.Add(x1 & x2 & x3)
            Next
        Next
    Next

    For varXR = 25 To 35
        For varEVD = 0 To 99
            For Each c As String In combinations
                Console.WriteLine(varXR & varEVD & c)
            Next
        Next
    Next
```